# Firebase Scheduled Function Incorrectly Runs Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have a Firebase scheduled function that incorrectly executes multiple times per scheduled run.

This behavior is inconsistent.

For example, today the function kicked off five times during its scheduled run, while it executed as intended yesterday.

[image: scheduled job logs]

Checking my logs, I am not seeing any obvious failures.

Here is how I have configured the job - note, there is no retry config:

```js
const myScheduledJob = functions
  .runWith({
    secrets: [...],
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
  })
  .pubsub.schedule('0 7 * * 1-5')
  .timeZone('America/Chicago')
  .onRun(async () => {
    ...job with 500+ network request being made
  });
```

Curious if anyone has encountered a similar situation before and how to resolve.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You seem to be making the assumption that the problem is in the definition of the function itself and has nothing to do with its implementation. I'll challenge that assumption and ask you to provide a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) that anyone can use to observe the same behavior that you observe with the same code.

Comment: Good point, @DougStevenson! Will update 

Comment: Since you're making asynchronous calls, make sure that you return a promise that resolves when all the async tasks have completed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?gen=2nd#node.js_1

Comment: Check the [Cloud Scheduler](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler) service for the associated GCP project from your developer console. I suspect that you might have multiple instances running.